# Subset dataframe based on levels

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement, nested

I have the following dataframe in R. I want to subset it based on three criteria,**for each unique value of x** within **each level of id**

1. If there is only 1 value of x, keep that row
2. If x has the same value of z, with two different values of y, keep the row where y **does not** = 1.3
3. If x has three values of z, keep the two rows where y **does not** = 1.3

```html
id x y z
a 1 0.2 100
a 2 1 200
a 2 1.3 200
b 1 0.5 400
b 1 1 500
b 1 1.3 600
```

the solution would look like this:

```html
id x y z
a 1 0.2 100
a 2 1 200
b 1 0.5 400
b 1 1 500
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'id', 'x' and `filter` based on the conditions

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(id, x) %>% 
   filter(n() == 1|(n() > 1 & y != 1.3))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), x = c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), y = c(0.2, 1, 1.3, 0.5, 1, 1.3), z = c(100L, 
200L, 200L, 400L, 500L, 600L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```